# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type : This is not returned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below bean defined as part a A.jar

```
package abc;

@Component
public class ParentInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

}
```

I have created another bean in a different project under a different package by extending ParentInerceptor

```
package xyz;

@Component
public class ChildInterceptor extends ParentInterceptor {

}
```

In my SpringBoot app , I have a bean defined similar to below

```
@ComponentScan({"abc","xyz"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public Data dataRepo(ParentInterceptor p){

}


}
```

When I run the main method , I am expecting to see NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException as 2 beans are of same type. However I see both the beans are loaded and ParentInterceptor is being used. Is there a reason why the error is not being thrown?

EDIT

However when i did the below , I was able to see the error being thrown. However I am still unable to understand why an error wasn't thrown in the case listed above.

```
package xyz;

@Component
public class ChildInterceptor1 extends ChildInterceptor {

}
```

Application Class:

```
 @ComponentScan({"abc","xyz"})
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx =  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Data dataRepo(ChildInterceptor p){

    }


    }
```

EDIT 2

I also tried to check if the child bean indeed extending the parent using the code below -

```
ctx.getBeansOfType(ParentInterceptor.class)
```

This returns ParentInterceptor  & ChildInterceptor. So I am not really sure why Spring is not returning the error!

Comment: I agree that the first case should fail. Can you share a complete example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks Andy. It is part of a large project , but I am unable to create a standalone app to replicate this issue. However I am still trying to do that.

Comment: Is there any setting that would bypass this error and inject appropriate class? In my case , I am able to see the ParentInterceptor  being injected. However when I set @Primary annotation on ClientInterceptor , ClientInterceptor is being injected. Is there any configuration along with SpringBootApplication annotation (convention over configuration) , which enables Spring to choose appropriate beans without throwing an error? Sorry , I am still unable to come up with an example where I can replicate this. i am always getting NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException & looks like I am missing some config.

Comment: Could you add a Spring version?

Comment: Hi Christopher , I am using v 4.1.8

Answer (score 0):

In your first example (Parent and Child), i have the correct behaviour, which is the NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException thrown.

If you want to specify which bean to be injected, you can use the @Qualifier annotation:

```
@Bean
public Data dataRepo(@Qualifier("parentInterceptor") ParentInterceptor p) {

}
```

Optionally, you can give a name to a component:

```
@Component("foo")
```

and change the @Qualifier accordingly.